# If I add one column as list of enum, one row has many category, then it will be efficient or has better way to do this?

Tags: mysql, sql

Online store has many category. I want to implement this in mysql. If I add one column category as list of enum, then it will be efficient or has better way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: Typically, you would have a table of items, a table of categories, and a table recording which item belongs to which category.

Comment: Basically i want to show similar store , for this i need to add category column, based on this i can easily show similar stores

Comment: It depends but mostly it’s better to have it as a table in the database

Comment: for example amazon similar store is flipkart

Answer (score 0):

> Online store has many category.

This immediately suggests three tables:

- `stores`
- `categories`
- `storeCategories`

The third is called a "junction" or "association" table and it contains one row per store and category.

So, your question is whether you should use an `enum` for this purpose.  The answer is "no".